# Remove debug log from Console using Spark 1.6.2

Tags: java, apache-spark

Using Java, I start a basic Spark app using:

```
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("myApp").setMaster("local");
    JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    javaSparkContext.setLogLevel("INFO");
    SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(javaSparkContext);
```

I try to have the system a little less verbosy by adding the `setLogLevel`, but it does not take it. I still have a lot of Debug information.

Ideally, I would like to shut off all `org.apache.spark.*` except errors...

**Update #1:**

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-csv_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a file conf/log4j.properties.template, copy it and modify according to your need for logging.

```
cd spark/conf
cp log4j.properties.template log4j.properties
```

add rows to log4j.properties should work

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark=ERROR
```

**[Edit]**

If it is a maven java project, running a standalone spark. Copy the `log4j.properties` to `src/main/resources`, or to `src/test/resources` if it's for test cases. And modify accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @Rockie, I have seen that, but I do not know where spark/conf is... I integrated Spark in my through Maven, so everything is pretty Opaque... Do you know where would be spark/conf in this environment?

Comment: Do you mean that the Spark is loaded by maven. I would check the pom.xml file and see how it is loaded and modify accordingly

Comment: Yes, Maven takes care of everything... I updated my post with the pom